# Custom self-closing tags using Sanitize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sanitize

I'm using the `Sanitize` gem to clean up HTML https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize, but I want to allow a few custom self-closing tags. When I run the `Sanitize.fragment` method, I get html with a close tag. e.g.

```
Sanitize.fragment("<custom-tag> Text after tag", :elements => ['custom-tag'])
=> "<custom-tag> Text after tag</custom-tag>"
```

I want the output to be `"<custom-tag> Text after tag"` instead

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for `Sanitize` to know a custom tag is self-closing.

Either try using `<custom-tag />` to make the tag self-closing, or just `gsub` out the closing tags:

```
str = Sanitize.fragment("<custom-tag> Text after tag", :elements => ['custom-tag'])
str.gsub(/<\/custom-tag>/,'')
```

Comment: What about something like a `<br>` tag that doesn't require the trailing `/`, yet it still valid HTML?

Comment: @sguha I assume Sanitize is smart enough to know which *real* tags are self-closing, and which aren't. It can't know if you make up tags. I said: "There is no way for Sanitize to know a **custom** tag is self-closing".

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way I can tap into the mechanism that `Sanitize` uses to know that <br> and <img> tags don't need a closing tag.